# ngGrid: how to check whether row is selected or not

Tags: ng-grid

I have grid implemented using ngGrid, and now I want to make it editable only if the row is selected using checkBox is checked, how to find whether the checkbox is checked or not in ngGrid to make cells in that row editable ? I just want the cells in the selected rows are only editable, others should be non-editable.

Comment: The checkbox is a boolean value that comes from the Server and read only? Or can be checked/unchecked by the user, which wouldn't make much sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick way to do this in v2 is to set

```
cellEditableCondition: 'row.selected'
```

in your grid options. See [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YLfbL4?p=preview). If you use this method, though, you should **not** use `enableCellEditOnFocus`, because a single click will cause each clicked cell to be open for editing as soon as the row is selected. I believe this is a bug, but likely won't be resolved in v2.